# Is permission settings needed to execute KornShell (ksh) script in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, file-permissions, ksh

I am interested to know why is it that I can't run a specific *.ksh file. Is it due to permission settings? If it is, how can I work around that? I'm not logging on as the administrator, do I need to be an administrator to run *.ksh files?

Comment: make a "ls -als *.ksh" in the directory of the file and tell us what you see. i think it might be a restrictive permission setting

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to be administrator but you *do* need to have permissions.

If you want to run it with something like:

```
myscript.ksh
```

it will need to have execute privileges for you. If you have read but no execute, you can do:

```
ksh myscript.ksh
```

If you don't even have that, you're fresh out of luck.

Run the command:

```
ls -al myscript.ksh
```

(substituting the *actual* script name) to see the permissions. They'll be something like:

```
-rwxr-xr--  1  bob  plebs  <some other things>  myscript.ksh
```

which means read, write and execute for the owner (bob), read and execute for the group (plebs) and read only for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this chmod Unix shell command to make the KornShell (ksh) script executable:

```
chmod 755 foo.ksh
```

"755 means read and execute access for everyone and also write access for the owner of the file. When you perform chmod 755 filename command you allow everyone to read and execute the file, owner is allowed to write to the file as well." [chmod-755](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/chmod-755.shtml)